# Can't log in to OSX Server through VNC from Windows

Tags: osx-server

I'm trying to connect to a Mac Mini running OSX Server 10.9. I've managed to use RealVNC to reach the login screen, but when I try to log in using a user I created on the server itself, I get 'error 9' messages in the server logs. I have no idea what's causing this.

Comment: Is Apple Remote Desktop running on the server?  There's a preference in that app that prevents screen sharing when the app is active.

Comment: @MrRabbit I've found that the problem wasn't in my server settings, but in my keyboard layout, which is completely garbled. I'm using a Belgian Azerty keyboard, but it changes to some form of qwerty I've never seen before.